# Control Listview scroll?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

i wanna create a listview which behave like a wheel, i wanna the focus to stay in the middle of the screen and when i press the DPAD_DOWN the focused item take the place of the previous focused item, i hope that you understand me and help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this awesome library can help you http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i can't control this with dpad, in addition what i need is a listview. respect

Comment: It's open-source, take it and handle DPAD_DOWN directly. Why do you need listview? You wrote that you need wheel wiget, there it is. It support custom content items.

Comment: i wrote that i need a listview with a wheel behavior, i'm working on wheels library but without result :)

Comment: I wish you good luck on it :), for my experience it was hard to extend  listview/gallery